# How to prevent multiple network calls from a flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am building an app using flutter and I'm using the flutter_bloc package for managing state. I have a simple Avatar widget used for displaying for displaying profile photo of a user.

```
/// A widget for displaying a user profile avatar.
class UserAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The unique identifier for a particular user.
  final int userId;

  /// The size of the avatar.
  final double radius;

  UserAvatar({required this.userId, this.radius = 30}) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<UserInfoBloc>().add(UserInfoEvent.getUserInfo(userId));

    return BlocBuilder<UserInfoBloc, UserInfoState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return state.when(initial: () {
          return Text('Initial');
        }, loading: () {
          return Text('Loading');
        }, loaded: (user) {
          print(user);
          return Container(
            child: Avatar(
              shape: AvatarShape.circle(radius),
              loader: Center(
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Skeleton(
                    height: radius * 2,
                    width: radius * 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              useCache: true,
              sources: [NetworkSource(user.avatarUrl ?? '')],
              name: user.firstName!.trim(),
              onTap: () {
                //TODO implement Navigation to profile page
              },
            ),
          );
        }, error: () {
          return Text('error');
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that the widget will be used multiple times (when displaying a feed and there are contents by the same user). I initially just have the id of the user, then I try to make a network call and try to get the user. I've implemented some form of caching in my repository:

```
@LazySingleton(as: UserInfoRepository)
class UserInfoRepositoryImpl extends UserInfoRepository {
  final GetUserInfoRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;
  final GetUserInfoLocalDataSource localDataSource;

  UserInfoRepositoryImpl(
      {required this.remoteDataSource, required this.localDataSource});

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, User>> getUserInfo(int id) async {
    try {
      final existsInCache = localDataSource.containsUserModel(id);
      if (existsInCache) {
        return right(localDataSource.getUserModel(id));
      } else {
        final result = await remoteDataSource.getUserInfo(id);
        localDataSource.cacheUserModel(result);
        return right(result);
      }
    } on ServerExceptions catch (e) {
      return left(e.when(() => Failure(),
          requestCancelled: () => Failure.requestCancelled(),
          unauthorisedRequest: () => Failure.unauthorisedRequest(),
          badRequest: (e) => Failure.badRequest(e),
          notFound: () => Failure.notFound(),
          internalServerError: () => Failure.internalServerError(),
          receiveTimeout: () => Failure.receiveTimeout(),
          sendTimeout: () => Failure.sendTimeout(),
          noInternetConnection: () => Failure.noInternetConnection()));
    } on CacheException {
      return left(Failure.cacheFailure());
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I used the injectable package for dealing with my dependencies, and I've used the @LazySingleton annotation on the repository. But unfortunately, if I try to display two avatars of the same user, two separate network calls will be made. Of course, I don't want that. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why don't you add user to the state of the bloc when you fetch it once? and then check if user is in the state of the bloc or not and then make you local and network calls...

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?